# Binding UWP Page Loading/ Loaded to command with MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, prism

Preferrably written in PRISM (Prism.Core 6.2, Prism.Windows 6.02), but I also would like to know how to bind Command to Page Loading/ Loaded event in UWP with normal MVVM without Prism.

In WPF, it is achievable with:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In the ViewModel

```
public ICommand LoadedCommand { get; private set; }
public TheViewModelConstructor()
{
     LoadedCommand = new DelegateCommand(Load);
}
private async void Load()
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

But in UWP, System.Windows.Interactivity does not exist. Simply binding with

```
Loaded="{Binding LoadedCommand}"
```

or

```
Loading="{Binding LoadingCommand}"
```

will get compile error "Object reference not set an instance of an object".

The reason I wanted to do this is because there is an async method that needs to be done during or after Page is loaded (it cannot be inside ViewModel constructor). I could do it with code behind easily, but this is not MVVM.

How can I bind this Command properly?

Comment: Which event did you use for an async methods which are called after the page is appeared on UI ? I tried the loaded event similar to anwered solution, but still when I navigate to a screen, it hangs for 2-3 seconds and then page shows UI with loaded async data. Why does it happen so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Behaviors are also available in UWP. Simply add the [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/) package and you're ready to go.

*Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed v1.x*

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewLoadedCommand}" />
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

*Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed v2.x*

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewLoadedCommand}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: It works, but there should be `<core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>` before the `<core:InvokeCommandAction>`. Can you please fix before I mark it as accepted answer?

Comment: You're right, this seems to be a change between version 1.x (which we are still using) and 2 of the package. I've posted both in my answer.

Comment: While using CommandParameter, it always return's null. Any help?