# Bind Page Loaded/Loading event to an ICommand

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Let me start by saying I am already aware of all the responses to this question that discuss the [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed package.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500115/binding-uwp-page-loading-loaded-to-command-with-mvvm)

But I really need to know if that is *the only way* to execute code from the ViewModel when the View loads. I mean, binding button commands to an ICommand object is so straightforward.

You have this in the view (omitting boilerplate markup):

```
<Page xmlns:vm="using:FIFA.ViewModels">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:WeekInputViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Button Command="{Binding Save, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Page>
```

ViewModel would look like this:

```
namespace FIFA.ViewModels {
  class WeekInputViewModel : MainViewModelBase
  {
    private ICommand save_;
    public ICommand Save{
        get { return save_ = save_ ?? new DelegateCommand(SaveExec); }
    }
    private void SaveExec() {
        // To be ran
    }
}
```

And this is the MainViewModelBase:

```
namespace FIFA.ViewModels
{
  public abstract class MainViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

My immediate assumption was that if I wanted to run code when the Page (the View) was loaded or loading, it would be using this same exact process. But it doesn't work. In this case, VS would complain that the ICommand I am trying to bind to isn't a method. And let me be clear on what I am talking about:

```
<Page Loaded="{Binding //SOLUTION_HERE//}">
```

**Is there a simpler, more straightforward way to run code when a View loads/is loading than using the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed package?** I just really dislike the mess that using that package would add to my XAML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simpler, more straightforward way to run code when a View loads/is loading than using the `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed` package?

You could use `x:bind` to approach, then create redirect `PageLoad()` method in the view model and give page model instance a `x:Name` like following.

```
<Page x:Class="Hamburger5.Views.MainPage"
      .......

      Loaded="{x:Bind  ViewModel.PageLoad}"

      xmlns:vm="using:Hamburger5.ViewModels" mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
    </Page.DataContext>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public void PageLoad() => OnLoad();
private void OnLoad()
{
// do some thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Loaded` is an event that you may handle in the code-behind of your `Page`, and simply execute the command of the view model from the event handler:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WeekInputViewModel viewModel = DataContext as WeekInputViewModel;
        if (viewModel != null)
            viewModel.SaveCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

You don't have to involve any XAML markup at all if you don't want to.

Compared to XAML solution enabled by the `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed` package, this solution simply executes the exact same view model command from the very same view - programmatically.