# NullReferenceException: AutoSuggestBox

Tags: c#, winui-3

WinUI 3 Desktop WindowsAppSDK (1.2.230313)

I'm recieving a NullReferenceException on an AutoSuggestBox component when typing in it. When debugging, the breakpoints never hit their methods, and the application breaks with the following error image:

[image]

My View looks like this:

```
<AutoSuggestBox QueryIcon="Find" 
                                ItemsSource="{x:Bind AP.ViewModel.Entities, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                TextChanged="{x:Bind AP.ViewModel.AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged}"
                                SuggestionChosen="{x:Bind AP.ViewModel.AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen}"
                                QuerySubmitted="{x:Bind AP.ViewModel.AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted}"/>
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is marked as duplicate, but these 
 (AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged, AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen, AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted) are methods right? AFAIK, you can't (the compiler won't let you) directly bind methods to events. You need to use [Behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40502513/2411960) for this.

Comment: Best guess, but the ViewModel is probably null... thus it's a duplicate.

Comment: I found the problem being the ViewModel.Entities was an empty/null  observablecollection. Once I seeded it with info, things worked ok. The methods do bind when you declare the TypedEventHandler in the ViewModel, and bind them in the Presenter class. 

Stupid mistake